# How to Kill/Disable the Command/Function Launched when We Click the RadioButton in Python-Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

1. I am pretty new to using Python-Tkinter.
2. I am trying to create a frame work where based on some user inputs the widgets needs to change.
3. For example first, it asks the user you want to choose option1 or option2.
4. If option1 is chosen, then a command/function should be executed. Similarly, if Option 2 is chosen different functionality should work.
5. Similarly, if I toggle between option1 and option2, the function/command should change/get disabled accordingly.
6. Below is the piece of code which I tried, but then when I choose option1 it executes the option1 command/function.
7. Then when I choose option2, the option1 commands still stays and option2 command opens up.
8. And if I toggle further, all the windows keeps adding to the previous window.
9. How to basically disable/kill the options according to the selection of radio button?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
v = IntVar()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Label(root, 
      text="What You Want To Create: ",
      justify = LEFT, 
      padx = 0).pack()


def enableEntryComObjName():
    entry = Entry()
    entry.pack(side='bottom')
    entry.configure(state="normal")    
    entry.update()

def singlecomponent():
    #selection = "Which Single Component/Object You Wanted To Create: "
    #label.config(text = selection)
    Label(root, 
          text="Which Single Component/Object You Wanted To Create: ",
          justify = LEFT, 
          padx = 0).pack()
    Radiobutton(
                text="Transaction Object",
                padx= 20,
                variable=v,
                value=1).pack(anchor=W)
    #selection = "Enter The Component/Object Name You Wanted To Create: "
    #label.config(text = selection)
    Label(root, 
          text="Enter The Component/Object Name You Wanted To Create: ",
          justify = LEFT, 
          padx = 0).pack()
    enableEntryComObjName()

def completecomponent():
    Label(root, 
          text="How Many Boxes You Want To Create: ",
          justify = LEFT, 
          padx = 0).pack()
    enableEntryComObjName()
    Label(root, 
          text="What Type Of Interface You Wanted To Create: ",
          justify = LEFT, 
          padx = 0).pack()
    Radiobutton(root,
            text="Default Interface",
            padx= 20,
            variable=v,
            value=1,
            command=singlecomponent).pack(anchor=W)
    Radiobutton(root,
            text="User Defined Interface",
            padx = 20,
            variable=v,
            value=2,
            command=completevip).pack(anchor=W)


Radiobutton(root,
            text="Single Component",
            padx= 20,
            variable=v,
            value=1,
            command=singlecomponent).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(root,
            text="Complete Component",
            padx = 20,
            variable=v,
            value=2,
            command=completecomponent).pack(anchor=W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
mainloop()
```

Kindly help me regarding the same.

Thanks & Regards,
Vimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save widgets references and use `pack_forget()` to hide them when needed.

If `option1` is chosen, then hide widgets shown by `option2`. Similarly, if `option2` is chosen hide widgets shown by `option1`.

You can save widgets references in a list or use variable names.

This is a basic example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
v = IntVar()

group1 = []
group2 = []

group1.append( Entry(root) )
group1[0].insert(0, "Entry1")

group1.append( Button(root, text='Button1') )

group2.append( Entry(root) )
group2[0].insert(0, "Entry2")
group2.append( Button(root, text='Button2') )

def show1():

    for w in group2:
        w.pack_forget()

    for w in group1:
        w.pack()

def show2():
    for w in group1:
        w.pack_forget()

    for w in group2:
        w.pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text="Single Component",
            padx= 20,
            variable=v,
            value=1,
            command=show1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(root,
            text="Complete Component",
            padx = 20,
            variable=v,
            value=2,
            command=show2).pack(anchor=W)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rawly For You Inputs.. Will give a try @ my end. It would be great if you can post a basic example to save widgets reference and hiding them. Appreciate your timely help.

Comment: @vimo  I am glade to help you. Check this example.